# TensorFlow: Plotting a graph that describes data points and decision boundary

Tags: tensorflow

I would like to achieve something similar:

https://rootpy.github.io/root_numpy/_images/plot_multiclass_1.png

What would be the most elegant solution? Get the weights, bias, function and data and plot it with some other tool or does TensorFlow have support for that?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, Tensorflow does not directly support plotting decision boundaries.

It is certainly not the most elegant solution, but you can create a grid. Classify each point of the grid and then plot it. For example:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

"""
Solve the XOR problem with Tensorflow.

The XOR problem is a two-class classification problem. You only have four
datapoints, all of which are given during training time. Each datapoint has
two features:

      x    o

      o    x

As you can see, the classifier has to learn a non-linear transformation of
the features to find a propper decision boundary.
"""

__author__ = "Martin Thoma"

import tensorflow as tf
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

# The training data
XOR_X = [[0, 0], [0, 1], [1, 0], [1, 1]]  # Features
XOR_Y = [[0], [1], [1], [0]]  # Class labels
XOR_Y = [[1, 0], [0, 1], [0, 1], [1, 0]]  # Target values

assert len(XOR_X) == len(XOR_Y)  # sanity check

# The network
nb_classes = 2
input_ = tf.placeholder(tf.float32,
                        shape=[None, len(XOR_X[0])],
                        name="input")
target = tf.placeholder(tf.float32,
                        shape=[None, nb_classes],
                        name="output")
nb_hidden_nodes = 2
# enc = tf.one_hot([0, 1], 2)
w1 = tf.Variable(tf.random_uniform([2, nb_hidden_nodes], -1, 1),
                 name="Weights1")
w2 = tf.Variable(tf.random_uniform([nb_hidden_nodes, nb_classes], -1, 1),
                 name="Weights2")
b1 = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([nb_hidden_nodes]), name="Biases1")
b2 = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([nb_classes]), name="Biases2")
activation2 = tf.sigmoid(tf.matmul(input_, w1) + b1)
hypothesis = tf.nn.softmax(tf.matmul(activation2, w2) + b2)
cross_entropy = -tf.reduce_sum(target * tf.log(hypothesis))
train_step = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.1).minimize(cross_entropy)

# Start training
init = tf.initialize_all_variables()
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(init)

    for i in range(100000):
        sess.run(train_step, feed_dict={input_: XOR_X, target: XOR_Y})

        if i % 10000 == 0:
            print('Epoch ', i)
            print('Hypothesis ', sess.run(hypothesis,
                                          feed_dict={input_: XOR_X,
                                                     target: XOR_Y}))
            print('w1 ', sess.run(w1))
            print('b1 ', sess.run(b1))
            print('w2 ', sess.run(w2))
            print('b2 ', sess.run(b2))
            print('cost (ce)', sess.run(cross_entropy,
                                        feed_dict={input_: XOR_X,
                                                   target: XOR_Y}))

            # Visualize classification boundary
            xs = np.linspace(-5, 5)
            ys = np.linspace(-5, 5)
            pred_classes = []
            for x in xs:
                for y in ys:
                    pred_class = sess.run(hypothesis,
                                          feed_dict={input_: [[x, y]]})
                    pred_classes.append((x, y, pred_class.argmax()))
            xs_p, ys_p = [], []
            xs_n, ys_n = [], []
            for x, y, c in pred_classes:
                if c == 0:
                    xs_n.append(x)
                    ys_n.append(y)
                else:
                    xs_p.append(x)
                    ys_p.append(y)
            plt.plot(xs_p, ys_p, 'ro', xs_n, ys_n, 'bo')
            plt.show()
```

which gives

[image]